# Switch statement inside if statement

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement

I am trying to have a switch statement inside of an if statement checking integers

```
if variable <= 3 {
    // code
    switch variable {
    case 0: 
        println("0 case")
    case 1: 
        println("1 case")
    case 2: 
        println("2 case")
    case 3: 
        println("3 case")
    default:
        println("error")
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error for each case

```
 Binary operator '~=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Int?'
```

I do not understand why this wouldn't work.

Comment: Show where you declared and assigned `variable`

Answer (score 2):

`3` is an `Int` but `variable` is an `Int?` (an optional `Int`). You have to unwrap it.

For example, you can check if it's `nil` in the `if` statement. If it's not, then it's safe to force-unwrap (with `!`) inside the scope of that conditional:

One of many possible approaches:

```
if variable <= 3 && variable != nil {
    // code
    switch variable! {
    case 0:
        println("0 case")
    case 1:
        println("1 case")
    case 2:
        println("2 case")
    case 3:
        println("3 case")
    default:
        println("error")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

var variable : `Int`?  will not work

```
var variable = 2
//var variable : Int? // will not work

if variable <= 3 {
// code
switch variable {
case 0:
    println("0 case")
case 1:
    println("1 case")
case 2:
    println("2 case")
case 3:
    println("3 case")
default:
    println("error")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `variable` is an Optional, be aware that if it's `nil` then in your initial `if` statement the expression `nil <= 3` returns `true`.

So, the most comprehensive form your can choose (IMHO) is:

```
var variable : Int? = ...

switch variable {
case .Some(0):
    print("1 case")
case .Some(1):
    print("2 case")
case .Some(3):
    print("3 case")
case .Some(let x):
    print("We got \(x)")
case .None:
    print("variable is nil")
}
```

**Note:**
`print` is Swift 2.0. Use `println` in Swift 1.2